# Kentico web analytics - countries

Tags: kentico, web-analytics

I have a Kentico 7 website I need to know the trafic and from where .
I've enabled Web Analytics, it's recording page views.
It is recording entry and exit pages, and visitors in general, but I noticed in visitiors - - countries a trafic visitors from country I don't sell my website there.
Is there a way to know a
specific information about the visitor like IP Address in the same page (analytics page) to make sure that the trafic county is correct.

Second question: is there a way to add my IP address some where to differentiate between external and internal use in analytics page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to  to add an IP address to differentiate between external and internal use in analytics page.

I highly recommend using Google or Segment analytics for tracking purposes as they are much more accurate.

Also I highly highly **highly** recommend you look at upgrading to a recent version of Kentico (V13). Kentico 7 is a very old legacy version of Kentico. Because of that and the way that analytics were written I'd wager you are not getting the best results in 7.